# in access how to draw tables on Report and then export it on word

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

I need to draw a table within report, I tried to use line  (from controls in design tab in design view) and I it works , I have tables in report . but I need to export my report in word , and pdf . For pdf I can see tables that I created, but in word I dont have tables. Are there other ways to create tables within report?

Comment: You probably want to export the data to Word, and then use VBA to change the `activedocument.tables` object properties in the word document from Access.  For example, to create the border tables,  `.borders.enable = true` property with the above object will create table around your data.  Use `.columns(x).width` to set column widths.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have added your fields into your report, if you select the ones you want in a table, you can select stacked or tabular in the 'Arrange' tab in 'Design view'. This will arrange the fields in columns or rows. You can then add labels and text boxes wherever you want in relation to the table you have created.

You can also change the format of the table by accessing the property sheet for each or multiple table "cells" and changing gridline properties in the 'Format' tab.

Comment: thanks alot, I already tried it.it works when I creat report in access. but problem is , now I want to export report in word (RTF)[EXternal Dat tab->export section-> more-> to word which gives in RTF] . but then in word; I dont have those lines, I have just data without tables .

Comment: Would it be possible for you to export it into Excel and then add the Excel spreadsheet into word document?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the YouTube video below.  It does exactly what you want.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-xqk8-dRwBY

Also, check out this link, to see how to save a Report to a PDF.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43gbFu3eC54

Comment: thanks alot.I exactly watched  first video before writing a question. ´( I dont know who gave negetive grade but solution is not there). 
this video helps to draw table in report I also used that method to draw tables . but problem is when I export my report in word (RTF) then those line will be vanished.  
In pdf format i have those lines.