# in access when a Report containging tabulated data exported to word all table borders/lines disappears

Tags: ms-word, ms-access-reports

I made a Report containing rows and column. When Exported it to word document ([EXternal Dat tab->export section-> more->). All the text data exported except border lines of tabulated data.

- Is there any solution to keep intect the borders of table in expored word/rtf document.

I have also tried "activedocument.tables. borders.enable = true " [earlier suggested][1] but no table object found in expored rtf word file. Images- output in pdf format and output in rtf .

[1]: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366381/in-access-how-to-draw-tables-on-report-and-then-export-it-on-word![enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366381/in-access-how-to-draw-tables-on-report-and-then-export-it-on-word!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bruru.jpg)